# How to fix error "incorrect permissions on /usr/lib/policykit-1" when uninstalling app from Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I am getting error when I am trying to uninstall slack "incorrect permissions on `/usr/lib/policykit-1`" in Ubuntu.

Please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the permission by the following command.

```
sudo chmod +s policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

Try removing app now. Hope it helps.